# selenuim in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, selenium

In a file called e2e.js wrote:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

driver.get('https://www.google.co.il/');
```

I installed selenium-webdriver,

I installed chromedriver.

It was written after the installation:

**found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details**

And command  node e2e.js  the error is:

**Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version 
of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.**

Comment: What's the exact problem? Your bot is not opening Chrome? If so, you will need to insert chromedriver's path into your Chrome() object. Check here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Comment: What's the syntax for that in React

Comment: You found the solution?

Comment: Yes! thank you! you gave me direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const path = require('chromedriver');// **added import** 




const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
driver.get('https://www.google.co.il/');
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.